# Phpunit click on anchor tag element instead of submit button

Tags: php, forms, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit

My Form doesn't have a *Submit* button. Instead I used an anchor tag.

```
<a href="#" 
        onclick="javascript:submitOfQuestion();"
                                    data-toggle="dropdown"
                                    class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"><i
                                    class="fa fa-upload icon-white"></i> Upload </a>
```

And I wrote the below test method.

```
/** @test */
public function testUploadQuestion(){


    $this->visit('/upload_question')
        ->select('Computer', 'subject')
        ->select('7 - 10', 'ageCategory')
        ->type('Test Case Test Question 1', 'question')
        ->attach('C:\xampp\htdocs\IntelliKid\public\test_resources\Capture2.JPG', 'file[]')
        ->type('Test Case Test Answer 1', 'ans1')
        ->type('Test Case Test Answer 2', 'ans2')
        ->type('Test Case Test Answer 3', 'ans3')
        ->type('Test Case Test Answer 4', 'ans4')
        ->press('Upload')
        ->see('Success!');

}
```

But I get the following error.

```
1) UploadQuestionTest::testUploadQuestion
InvalidArgumentException: Could not find a form that has submit button [Upload].

C:\xampp\htdocs\IntelliKid\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithPages.php:731
C:\xampp\htdocs\IntelliKid\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithPages.php:711
C:\xampp\htdocs\IntelliKid\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithPages.php:691
C:\xampp\htdocs\IntelliKid\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithPages.php:678
C:\xampp\htdocs\IntelliKid\tests\UploadQuestionTest.php:33
C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:176
C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:129

FAILURES!
Tests: 6, Assertions: 14, Errors: 1.
```

Comment: What's the specific question you'd like to address?

Answer (score 2):

You probably figured this out by now. But another user might have a similar problem, try replacing your: *`->press('Upload')` **to** `->click('Upload')`* When you just say "`->press`" it expects to receive a button.

Try this and see if it works first. If I were you I'd also go to the view and give my href link an *`id="Upload"`* so that your unit test can identify it when I say *`->click('Upload')`*

I hope this helps.
~T